# C# Update out parameter in another function

Tags: c#, dictionary, design-patterns, reference

I have class that defines the following methods -

```
void DoAction1(out object result1)
{
    // Do some work and set result1
}

void DoAction2(out object result2)
{
    // Do some work and set result2
}

void ExecuteAllActions()
{
    //Some more execution work happens here 
    // which may cause modifications to  result1 and result2
}
```

Is there some way I can store a ref to the two out params and update them in ExecuteAllActions() function?

Comment: I am just curious, why do you have `void` functions with `out` parameters`?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to accomplish here. Only `DoAction1` can change the out parameter value of that method, what exactly do you want to do in `ExecuteAllActions`? And why do you have 1 out parameter in a method that doesn't return anything, why not return the value instead?

Comment: More information definitely required - please provide some context, ideally a [mcve] (which presumably won't actually work, but should make it clearer what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: Some constraints - I have no control over DoAction1() and DoAction2(). Added some more clarification to my question.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited amount of information you have provided, all I can say is that you are doing it wrong. As a general rule, you never write a method with an `out` parameter and a `void` return type, since you can just return whatever object you would have assigned to the `out` parameter. This type of approach is much easier and simpler:

```
object DoAction1()
{
    // Do some stuff and return a result object
}

object DoAction2()
{
    // Do some stuff and return a result object
}

void ExecuteAllActions()
{
    var actionResult1 = DoAction1();
    var actionResult2 = DoAction2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is -- deliberately -- no way in the .NET type system to store a ref to a variable. This at a stroke avoids the problem of storing a reference to a variable whose lifetime has ended.

However, I note that *a one-element array* is an object that can be passed as a reference type, whose sole element is a variable that can be passed as ref or out.  Obviously you *can* store a one-element array, pass it around as you like and so on.

That said, if you need to resort to tricks like this, something is probably wrong in the design.  Try to make APIs that take values and return values, not take variables and mutate them.